# Get the Original CREATE EXTERNAL DDL statement for a Table in Athena

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena

In Athena all the tables are EXTERNAL tables. Athena provides an option to generate the CREATE table DDL statement by running the command "SHOW CREATE TABLE <Table_Name>.

Is there a way to get the original DDL statement executed for the table in Athena?
Does ATHENA store those DDLs somewhere which can be fetched programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You've kinda answered your own question. You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` to generate the DDL statement.
You can get the `CREATE TABLE` DDL statement from Athena, by calling [`StartQueryExecution()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html) from your code, waiting for the query to complete and then downloading the results file or using the [`GetQueryResults()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueryResults.html) API.

Athena uses the Glue Data Catalog as a Hive metastore. You can call the Glue [APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-tables.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-tables-GetTable) to get the table metadata, but it won't be a `CREATE TABLE` statement.